# WireGuard: Limiting download & upload bandwidth

Tags: iptables, vpn, tc, wireguard

I'm trying to limit download and upload speed of each wireguard peer to 512kbit.

**The problem is** that my following commands, **only limits download bandwidth** of peer and doesn't limit upload bandwidth. Any help would be appreciated.

tc rules for example peer with ip 10.7.0.2 and iptables mark 12:

```
tc qdisc add dev eth0 root handle 1: htb
tc qdisc add dev wg0 root handle 1: htb

tc class add dev eth0 parent 1:1 classid 1:12 htb rate 512kbit ceil 512kbit
tc qdisc add dev eth0 parent 1:12 sfq perturb 10
tc filter add dev eth0 protocol ip parent 1: prio 1 handle 12 fw flowid 1:12

tc class add dev wg0 parent 1:1 classid 1:12 htb rate 512kbit ceil 512kbit
tc qdisc add dev wg0 parent 1:12 sfq perturb 10
tc filter add dev wg0 protocol ip parent 1: prio 1 handle 12 fw flowid 1:12
```

And with iptables, I mark peer with number 12, so tc does limit it:

```
iptables -I FORWARD -s 10.7.0.2 -j MARK --set-mark 12
iptables -I FORWARD -d 10.7.0.2 -j MARK --set-mark 12
```

Thanks!

Comment: i found a similar script https://gist.github.com/Lakshanz/19613830e5c6f233754e12b25408cc51 take a look into it

Comment: @djdomi, Thank you. I've tried that but with no luck. Maybe there is something special with wireguard itself?

Comment: [Chat with me](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126791/thechat)

Comment: The problem has been solved with: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65248666/3411911

Comment: then answer the question on your own and accept it

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem using this code, from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65248666/3411911

```
export IF_INET=eth0
export LIMIT=300kbit

tc qdisc add dev ${IF_INET} ingress

tc filter add dev ${IF_INET} protocol ip ingress prio 2 u32 match ip dst 0.0.0.0/0 action police rate ${LIMIT} burst ${LIMIT}
tc filter add dev ${IF_INET} protocol ip ingress prio 2 u32 match ip src 0.0.0.0/0 action police rate ${LIMIT} burst ${LIMIT}
```